# Javascript: assigning data to Multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert Java code to Javascript and I am trying to assign data to 3 dimensional array and I am getting  "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object " error. Following is my code. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
var initData = [[2], [12], [2]];

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    initData[0][i][0] = -1;
    initData[0][i][1] = -1;
    initData[1][i][0] = -1;
    initData[1][i][1] = -1;
}
```

Comment: Well, you have a 2D array.

Comment: Your `initData` is a 2 dimentional array of arrays, each of those arrays has a single cell. I don't think this is what you meant.

Comment: You cannot declare dimensions of javascript arrays, because there are no multidimensional arrays in JS. They're just one-dimensional lists that can contain arbitrary values (including other lists).

Comment: in your code, [12] is an array containing one element (the number 12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> [[2], [12], [2]];
> ```

That's not a declaration of dimensions, that's four [array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals). There are no multidimensional arrays in JS. They're just one-dimensional lists that can contain arbitrary values (including other lists).

To create and fill an array that contains other arrays you have to use the following:

```
var initData = []; // an empty array
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    initData[i] = []; // that is filled with arrays
    for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        initData[i][j] = []; // which are filled with arrays
        for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            initData[i][j][k] = -1; // which are filled with numbers
        }
    }
}
```

or, to apply your [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding):

```
var initData = [[], []]; // an array consisting of two arrays
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    // which each are filled with arrays that consist of two numbers
    initData[0][i] = [-1, -1];
    initData[1][i] = [-1, -1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initData is a list of three lists, [2], [12] and [2]. Each one with one element.

In order to init a list(or array), you must do

```
var initData = [];
```

Then store in initData another list, like `initData[0] = []` and so on... like it's mentioned, arrays/lists in javascript aren't initialized with a limit size.